# Tracking Volunteers

Tags: civivolunteer

I work within the outreach department of my organization and one of our primary functions is tracking volunteers and their hours per year. Does anyone track this in civi? What function (s) do you use to track this data?

*Note I am not trying to track volunteers under events (as we have many events/activities that can be counted as volunteer hours) I just want to be able to input volunteer information and their accumulated hours per month for the year.

*P.S currently we are tracking everything in excel

Answer (score 2):

Hi Khaela and welcome on SE.

You can use 'Activities' for example and create a new type of activity labelled `Volunteering`.

Every time someone helps, he or a leader could use it and fill in the `date` and `duration` with status `completed`. Then you can create and export all the fancy exports you need for reporting.

This could also be recorded with a front-end form if your volunteers don't have any user access to CiviCRM.

Just one simple process with core functionalities.